# How to create an instance of a class in a service(FirebaseService)

Tags: java, android

I want to create an object of a different class, which contains required methods, here in my service how to create an object of that class and call the method required.

I tried doing this but what parameters should be passed in below code:

```
private PictureCapturingServiceImpl pictureService;

pictureService = new PictureCapturingServiceImpl();

// here its actually asking to pass Android.app.activity but this is a 
// class extends Fire-base Service,so what parameters should be passed .

pictureService.startCapturing(this);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really need an `Activity` instance here, then you should start some `Activity` to perform this operation.

If you need instance of `android.content.Context`, then you can pass instance of your service.